# Understanding matrix conditioning at a glance

Tags: matrices

I'm working on my Master's, in the field of computational fluid dynamics, where we have to solve the system $Ax = b$ a lot. As far as I can figure out, if the matrix $A$ is ill-conditioned it is possible that a small residual $r = |Ax-b|$ does not necessarily correspond with an accurate solution to the system.

Is there a "rule of thumb" as to how I can think about an ill-conditioned matrix? From what I can figure out, an ill-conditioned matrix may have large differences (close to machine precision) between some of its entries. Is this correct? And does diagonal dominance have any effects on conditioning?

Comment: If a matrix is nearly singular, it is ill conditioned. You loose about the number of digit precision as the magnitude of the condition number (just rule of thumb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $\det(A)$ has a very small value ($A$ is almost singular), there's a high possibility that you have an ill-conditioned matrix. How small you ask? You need a reference against which the determinant can be measured. The reference here is called the norm of the matrix $\|A \|$.

There are several "popular" norms in the literature:
$$\|A \|=\sqrt{\sum_i\sum_ja_{ij}^2}  \tag{Euclidean norm}$$
$$\|A \|=\sum_i\sum_j|a_{ij}|$$
$$\|A \|=\max_{i,j}\{a_{ij}\}$$
$$\|A \|=\max_i\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|$$

If you're using MATLAB for example, you can define $\text{cond}(A)=\|A \|  \|A^{-1} \|$(condition number). If $\text{cond}(A)$ is close to unity, then the matrix is well conditioned. And as $\text{cond}(A)\rightarrow \infty$ the matrix gets more ill-conditioned. However, for very large matrices, computing the norm is quite expensive, so in most cases, we're content with comparing the determinant with the magnitudes of the elements of the matrix.

Concerning diagonal dominance: to my knowledge, having a diagonally dominant matrix is helpful when you're solving a system using methods like Gauss elimination with scaled row pivoting. However a diagonally dominant matrix is not necessarily well-conditioned.

Comment: @NicoleAndrew: As aside: The determinant is a bad indicator for condition. The diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(10^{-8}, 10^{-8})$ has small determinant but condition $1$. On the other hand the diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(10^8, 10^{-8})$ has determinant $1$ and condition $10^{16}$!

Comment: @user251257 but remember we're comparing with the norm. In the first case you proposed, the magnitude of the elements (or norm) and the determinant are ***both*** quite small, so we must jump to the condition number to verify the conditioning. In addition, in the second case you've given, comparing the determinant to the magnitudes is a good indicator of ill-conditioning without the need for computing the condition number since $10^{-8}<<<1<<<10^8$.

Comment: just for the 2nd case. The condition is $10^{16}$, which is considered basically singular on double precision architecture. By your logic, the matrix is still well conditioned, because $1 \ll 10^{8}$. Condition is about the ratio of the largest and smallest singular value. That ratio is norm invariant.

Comment: @user251257 Comparing the magnitudes reveals that they are very different, which is a sign of ill-conditiong.

Comment: well, the determinant is also dimension dependent, how about the  $9\times 9$ matrix $\operatorname{diag}(10^8, 10^{-1}, \dotsc, 10^{-1})$? how do you know if it is better or worse conditioned?

Comment: @user251257 there's a huge difference between the magnitudes of (i) the elements ($10^8>>10^{-1}$), and (ii) the norm (4th norm) and the determinant, which means it's ill-conditioned.

Comment: the condition is only $10^{9}$. so nearly half the digits are correct. there is a reason why people operate with condition instead of determinant. their connection is rather lose.

Comment: @user251257 Although the condition turned out to be rather large after all, I agree that condition is most certainly the way to go if precision is what you want. But as I've written, it's expensive, and relying on the determinant is good enough ***most*** of the time, especially in Engineering applications. Plus, diagonal matrices can be quickly solved without the use of any numerical method that requires conditioning to be applied. In the end, there is no absolutely ***right way*** with conditioning.